# Angular Reactive form custom validator not called when updateOn is set to submit

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to use a custom validator on my Angular 10 reactive form. It works fine when not specifying any updateOn options on the group. When I set it to 'submit', my validator is not called anymore.

First, here is my validator:

```
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export function DatePlusGrande(dateDebutName: string, dateFinName: string ): any {

  return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
    const dateDebutControl = formGroup.controls[dateDebutName];
    const dateFinControl = formGroup.controls[dateFinName];

    if (dateFinControl.errors && !dateFinControl.errors.plusPetitOuEgale) {
      return;
    }

    const dateDebut = dateDebutControl.value as Date;
    const dateFin = dateFinControl.value as Date;
    if (dateDebut.getTime() >= dateFin.getTime()) {
      dateFinControl.setErrors({ plusPetitOuEgale: true });
    } else {
      dateFinControl.setErrors(null);
    }
  };
}
```

Then my form group creation:

```
this.modifierFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        dateDebut: [entente.dateDebut, Validators.required],
        dateFin: [entente.dateFin]
      },
      {
        validator: DatePlusGrande('dateDebut', 'dateFin'),
        updateOn: 'submit'
      }
    );
```

My template...

```
<form *ngIf="caissesParticipantes" [formGroup]="modifierFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onModifier(modifierFormGroup)">
    <div class="p-grid">
      <div class="p-col-fixed" style="width: 100px;">Institution</div>
      <div class="p-col-fixed" style="width: 100px;">Transit</div>
      <div class="p-col-fixed" style="width: 200px;">Date de début</div>
      <div class="p-col-fixed" style="width: 200px;">Date de fin</div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-grid">
      <div class="p-col-fixed ro-input" style="width: 100px; ">
        {{caissesParticipantes.ententes[0].caisseParticipante.institution}}
      </div>
      <div class="p-col-fixed ro-input" style="width: 100px;">
        {{caissesParticipantes.ententes[0].caisseParticipante.transit}}
      </div>
      <div class="p-col-fixed" style="width: 200px;">
        <p-calendar dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" placeholder="aaaa-mm-jj" appendTo="body" [locale]="CalendrierLocalise" formControlName="dateDebut"
                    inputId="gca_modifier-input-date-debut"
                    [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" [yearRange]="yearRange"></p-calendar>
      </div>
      <div class="p-col-fixed" style="width: 200px;">
        <p-calendar dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" placeholder="aaaa-mm-jj" appendTo="body" [locale]="CalendrierLocalise" formControlName="dateFin"
                    inputId="gca_modifier-input-date-fin" [defaultDate]="defaultMinDate"
                    [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" [yearRange]="yearRange"></p-calendar>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="p-grid" style="margin-top: 10px">

      <div class="p-col" style="text-align: left">
        <button id="gca_modifier-btn-annuler" pButton type="button" label="{{'gestion-centres-activites.modifier-entente.annuler_btn' | translate}}" (click)="onAnnuler()"
                pTooltip="{{'gestion-centres-activites.modifier-entente.annuler_tooltip' | translate}}"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="p-col" style="text-align: right">
        <button id="gca_modifier-btn-modifier" pButton type="submit" label="{{'gestion-centres-activites.modifier-entente.modifier_btn' | translate}}"
                pTooltip="{{'gestion-centres-activites.modifier-entente.ok_tooltip' | translate}}"></button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
```

If I remove the "updateOn: 'submit'", it is fine.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to make it work, but I am still not sure why....
So instead of adding the validator in the group using formBuilder, I need to add it after:

```
    this.modifierFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        dateDebut: [entente.dateDebut, Validators.required],
        dateFin: [entente.dateFin, {updateOn: 'submit'}]
      },
      {
        updateOn: 'submit'
      }
    );

    this.modifierFormGroup.setValidators(DatePlusGrande('dateDebut', 'dateFin'));
```

This way it is working as expected.... But I still would like to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody have the same error, you need to change from key "validator" to key "validators".

It should look like this:

```
this.modifierFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        dateDebut: [entente.dateDebut, Validators.required],
        dateFin: [entente.dateFin]
      },
      {
        validators: DatePlusGrande('dateDebut', 'dateFin'),
        updateOn: 'submit'
      }
    );
```